# Probar si todos los elementos de una lista son string de enteros

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una dataframe con preguntas  y respuestas:

```
,Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 0.1,Unnamed: 0.1.1,URL,QID,Questions,Answers,QType
0,0,0,1,When do you think your next vacation can start?,"['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed']",
1,1,1,2,What are your preferences regarding medical policy (with additional cost)?,"[""Doctor's availability in hotel"", 'Ventilator availability in hotel', 'Tie-ups with nearby hospitals', 'Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care']",
2,2,2,3,What is your preferences of breakfast?,"['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options', 'Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable)', 'Packaged breakfast only']",
3,3,3,4,What is your preference for the basic necessity items?,"['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']",
4,4,4,5,Consumer Personality,[],
```

Quiero probar si todos los elementos de una lista son string de enteros

```
def classifier(l):
    l = ast.literal_eval(l)
    if all(type(int(item))==int for item in l):
        l = list(map(int, l))
        print("Todos los elementos de una lista son string de enteros")
df.apply(lambda x: classifier(df.Answers), axis = 1)
```

Pero obtengo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6878, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 186, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 296, in apply_standard
    values, self.f, axis=self.axis, dummy=dummy, labels=labels
  File "pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx", line 620, in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction
  File "pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx", line 128, in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result
  File "<input>", line 6, in <lambda>
  File "<input>", line 2, in classifier
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ast.py", line 91, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ast.py", line 90, in _convert
    return _convert_signed_num(node)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ast.py", line 63, in _convert_signed_num
    return _convert_num(node)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ast.py", line 55, in _convert_num
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: 0       ['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In n...
1       ["Doctor's availability in hotel", 'Ventilator...
2       ['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'B...
3       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ...
4                                                    ['']
                              ...                        
2953                                                 ['']
2954            ['<18', '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '>46']
2955              ['Female', 'Male', 'Prefer not to say']
2956    ['A-Levels', "Bachelor's degree", "Master's de...
2957    ['<1000', '1000-3000', '3001-5000', '5001-1000...
Name: Answers, Length: 2958, dtype: object
```

## Actualizacion

Mi principal problema es que olvidé intentar aplicarlo línea por línea.

```
def classifier(l):
    try: 
        print("l: ",l)
        l = ast.literal_eval(f"{l}")
        l = list(map(int, l))
    except ValueError:
        return None
    j = 0
    if not l:
        return None
    try: 
        if all(isinstance(x, int) for x in l):
            return "Likert Scale"
        else:
            return "Multiple Choice"
    except:
        return None

df.QType = df.apply(lambda row: classifier(row['Answers']), axis = 1)
```

Funciona mejor con eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé de que manera estás invocando la función `classifier()`, pero si estás pasándole como parámetro un número entero a secas ya vas por mal camino. Te voy a explicar la razón, te cito el apartado 32.2.3 (ast.**literal_eval**) de la [documentación de Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast-helpers):

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Esto quiere decir que el argumento que se le provee a la función `ast.literal_evals()` tiene que ser de tipo string, de lo contrario va a terminar en error. La comprobación de esto:

**Invocación:**

```
print(ast.literal_eval(69))
```

**Salida:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\ejemplo.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(ast.literal_eval(69))
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ast.py", line 99, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ast.py", line 98, in _convert
    return _convert_signed_num(node)
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ast.py", line 75, in _convert_signed_num
    return _convert_num(node)
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ast.py", line 66, in _convert_num
    _raise_malformed_node(node)
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ast.py", line 63, in _raise_malformed_node
    raise ValueError(f'malformed node or string: {node!r}')
ValueError: malformed node or string: 69
```

Ahora intentemos usar un string como parámetro:

**Invocación:**

```
print(ast.literal_eval("69"))
```

**Salida:**

```
69
```

No hay errores..

**¿Ahora, por qué pasa esto?**

Primero hay que entender que es un literal en Python:

Un literal en Python es una cadena de texto que el interprete puede interpretar. Por ejemplo: `"True"`. Cosas que puede reconocer como sintaxis valida.

Entonces la función que cumple `ast.literal_eval()` es devolver el **el literal del string proveído**. Esa es la razón de tu error, usas el número entero a secas como argumento de dicha función, y no lo percibías ya que tenías un control de excepciones (una muy mala coincidencia).

**Solución:**

En el fragmento de código que adjuntaste habían muchas cosas que no entendía, ya que no sabía el contexto detrás de tu código, pero las dos maneras correctas de evaluar el parámetro `l` son estas:

**Primera manera:**

Siempre se puede pasar el parámetro entre comillas, o si no casteando con `str()`:

```
def classifier(l: str):
    try: 
        x = ast.literal_eval(l)
        return "Funcionó"
    except ValueError:
        return None

print(classifier(str(69))
```

Salida:

```
Funcionó
```

**Segunda manera:**

Otra alternativa es hacer ese casting dentro de `classifier()` e invocando la función con un número entero como parámetro. Este casting se puede hacer con `str()`, pero el ejemplo que voy a adjuntar tiene el casting `f"{}"` para mostrar otra manera.

```
def classifier(l: int):
    try: 
        x = ast.literal_eval(f"{l}")
        return "Funcionó"
    except ValueError:
        return None

print(classifier(69))
```

La salida:

```
Funcionó
```

**Una última comprobación:**

Otra manera de asegurarnos que el literal si lo valoró como tipo `int` es retornando su tipo:

```
def classifier(l: int):
    try: 
        x = ast.literal_eval(f"{l}")
        return type(x)
    except ValueError:
        return None

print(classifier(69))
```

La salida:

```
<class 'int'>
```

Finalmente, te adjunto tu código editado para que te funcione (en teoría debería de funcionar):

```
import ast

def classifier(l):
    try: 
        l = ast.literal_eval(f"{l}")
        l = list(map(int, results))
    except ValueError:
        return None
    j = 0
    if not l:
        return None
    try: 
        if all(isinstance(x, int) for x in l):
            return "Likert Scale"
        else:
            return "Multiple Choice"
    except:
        return None

    df.QType = df.apply(lambda x: classifier(df.Questions), axis = 1)
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!